# How to most reliably/simply access the <html> element via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Use case: I'd like to dynamically add classes to the `<html>` element in my document so that some SASS mixins that are currently using `.class-name &` will work if applied within a selector which includes a body class -- otherwise I get `.class-name .body-class .rest-of-selector` which doesn't work unless `class-name` is applied at a higher level than the `<body>`

Previously I've used `document.body.classList.add` which seems neat, simple and robust.

In transitioning to add classes to the `<html>` element instead, I wondered what the equivalent code would be:

- `document.html` -- nope, no such thing it seems
- `document.rootElement` -- should work I think, but was `null` when I tested so not robust?!
- `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]` -- pretty clunky, but surely effective/robust?
- `document.body.parentElement` -- looks cleaner, should be reliable? Is this as direct as it gets?
- `document.querySelector('html')` as suggested by Louys below -- feels like we shouldn't need to query for it though?
- any other options I haven't thought of?

Comment: `document.querySelector("html")` ;)

Comment: or also `document.childNodes[1]` because it is supposed to be the doctype and the html node

Comment: Thanks @LouysPatriceBessette have added to the list in the question

Comment: @thibsc yes I think that would work doesn't feel particularly robust / simple so wouldn't be my favourite option

Comment: QuerySelector is simple and [robust](https://caniuse.com/?search=querySelector).

Comment: @DrMeers, I think you should prefer this following answer: [`document.documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) that give you directly the html node

Comment: @thibsc yes I think that might be best -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/rootElement points out that it has been deprecated in favour of `documentElement` which explains the `null` -- feel free to add that as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @thibsc and @LouysPatriceBessette said above, you have two excellent options in `document.querySelector("html")` and `document.documentElement`.

### **`document.querySelector("html")`**

[`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is an important function to know in general, in addition to `document.querySelectorAll()`. It returns the first matching element in document order, which for `document.querySelectorAll("html") will be the root html object.

[CanIUse compatibility chart](https://caniuse.com/?search=querySelector)

### **`document.documentElement`**

The `documentElement` property of the `document` object [(which can be thought of as an alias to the HTMLDocument object)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument) always refers to the root element, which in HTML is generally the `<html>` tag.

[CanIUse compatibility chart](https://caniuse.com/?search=document.documentElement)

### Speed

In my super-scientific speed test, document.documentElement seems faster today:

```
let date = Date.now();
for (var i=0; i<123456; i++) {
    a = document.querySelector("html");
    a.classList.toggle("hello");
    a = null;
}
console.log(Date.now() - date);
//result: 254

let a;
let date = Date.now();
for (var i=0; i<123456; i++) {
    a = document.documentElement;
    a.classList.toggle("hello");
    a = null;
}
console.log(Date.now() - date);
//result: 225
```

In the end, your question is about what "feels" good - but these are the best ways to access the `<html>` element. You were correct about your other alternatives:

- `document.html` -- doesn't exist
- `document.rootElement` -- deprecated
- `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]` -- [Clunky but robust](https://caniuse.com/?search=document.getElementsByTagName)
- `document.body.parentElement` -- [Also robust](https://caniuse.com/?search=parentElement)

But perhaps what you want is this:

```
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
$("html").classList.add("myClass");
```

Comment: `document.documentElement` is what I was after -- no need to query, pick from a list, etc -- simple and robust

Comment: I'm actually curious why you want to avoid querying - is it just personal preference? I query a lot so that's actually my preferred solution, but maybe it shouldn't be

Comment: Oooh, you might also be interested to know all the trivia in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document - you can access all links via the document.links property, for instance!

Comment: a query implies a DOM search, which is overkill for this, and less robust than a canonical access point

Comment: Not only is rootElement deprecated, it never applied to the HTML DOM in the first place - it's specific to the SVG DOM. And personally, I'd prefer documentElement over querySelector('html') for the same reason I prefer document.body over document.querySelector('body').